# Emacs widgets: editing problems with integer widget

Tags: widget

If I try to set up a buffer with just one `integer` widget, I have a very hard time editing the field.  The initial value seems stuck there and, if I try to edit it away I get a `End of file during parsing` error (obviously generated in the guts of the widget library or below).

Any idea about what is going on and how to make the `integer` widget do "the obvious", I suppose by changing the field keymap?

This is for Emacs 25.x to 28.x.  The code for the widget is below; you can uncomment the `:value` initialization just to see what happens.  Set it up in the usual way.

```lisp
        (widget-create 'integer
             :help-echo "Enter an integer..."
             ;; :value  " "
             :notify
             (lambda (w &rest ws)
               (ignore ws)
               (message "WIFT: %s" (widget-value w)))
             :size 4
           )
```

Comment: If you type a number after you get the EOF, it seems to go through: not sure what that means, but it may be a clue

Comment: Nope.  It just gets stuck again in a strange way.  Eventually you may force it to accept something, but the field gets screwed up and the :notify does not get properly called.

Comment: Found the bug.  It is a problem in the `:value-to-external` functions in the in `sexp` and `restricted-sexp` widgets (the `number` widget must also be fixed).

The library `:value-to-external` functions eventually do a `(read value)` where `value` is the widget value; alas, `value` can be `""` if you edit the field in a pretty standard way, causing the traditional minor demons to fly out of the nose, as a 'End of file during parsing' error gets signaled.

Specializing the widget fixes the problem, but a good solution need some work.

I will open an issue on the Emacs repo.